# Is role="banner" allowed on h1?

Tags: banner, wai-aria

The following markup got an error from the validator:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bla Bla Bla</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 role="banner">Bla Bla Bla</h1>

    <section role="main">
        <h1>Bla Bla Bla</h1>
        <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
    </section>

    <p role="contentinfo"><small>Bla Bla Bla</small></p>

</body>
</html>
```

The error is: **Error: Attribute role not allowed on element h1 at this point.**

Does that mean `role="banner"` must be on `header` element?

Comment: Yes it should be on a `<header>` tag or a `<div>` if you aren't using html5 yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ARIA role can be assigned to *any* HTML element. From [the WAI-ARIA docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/wai-aria.html#aria-role-attribute):

> 3.2.7.1 ARIA Role Attribute
>
> Every HTML element may have an ARIA role attribute specified.

---

However, there are various restrictions on what certain elements can be given as a role, mostly to prevent the implicit semantics from getting you into a muddled state with your explicit semantics.

If you look at tables in the W3C HTML5 specification linked to above, you'll see under "Implicit ARIA semantics" that a `h1` without a `hgroup` ancestor must have a role of either `heading` or `tab`, if set.

That's why you're getting the validation error.

You'll also see from those tables that `head` has a strong native semantic of `no role`, meaning you can't set that either - it must be set to `presentation`. I'm not sure if that's what you meant since you have no `header` element in your sample.

If you *did* have a `header` element then yes, you can set its role to `banner` - in fact that's all you're allowed to set it to (if you set it at all). That's also covered by those tables I've linked to above.

You could also *try* putting the `h1` inside a `section` with a `banner` role - that would have been my first attempt at fixing this.

Comment: So does the conclusion indicate that <h1> cannot have role="banner" and the validator has a bug so it didn't show an error for <p role="contentinfo">?

Comment: @Ian: No, there's no bug. `p` has neither strong native semantics nor a restriction in the default semantics table, so it can have any of the roles. `h1` has a specific limitation in the defaults table.

Comment: @IanY. H1 cannot have a banner role because it natively has a header/heading role, and that has stronger semantic value than banner. The contentinfo should probably be placed on the footer container vs the `p` because i assume you have more than one thing in there.